# What do the numbers in mySQL createTable methods mean?

Tags: mysql, database-schema, create-table

I have the following php script that builds the tables I need for my site.

```
include_once 'rcfunctions.php';

createTable('rcmembers', 'user VARCHAR(16), pass VARCHAR(16),
            INDEX(user(6))');

createTable('rcmessages', 
           'id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            auth VARCHAR(16), recip VARCHAR(16), pm CHAR(1),
            time INT UNSIGNED, message VARCHAR(4096),
            INDEX(auth(6)), INDEX(recip(6))');

createTable('rcfriends', 'user VARCHAR(16), friend VARCHAR(16),
            INDEX(user(6)), INDEX(friend(6))');

createTable('rcprofiles', 'user VARCHAR(16), text VARCHAR(4096),
            INDEX(user(6))');

            echo "Tables Created!";
```

I'd like to adapt this approach to create more tables that contain a variety of things. (namely objects?) I have no idea what the numbers indicate and vague on VARCHAR, CHAR, INDEX, etc. I'm sure there is a resource or guide somewhere for this. I've found the cheat sheet I need, but it doesn't mention numbers or conventions and is little overwhelming. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html

Comment: If you read the [relevant documentation pages](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/data-types.html) for each datatype, it does explain what those numbers are

Comment: does the creation of a table make an object anywhere in php?

Comment: No, it doesn't, why should it? The only connection between a MySQL datatable and PHP is one defined within individual PHP scripts written by yourself, there's no automagic connection between a database and PHP

Comment: is it possible to create a databases of objects?

Comment: Perhaps you should start by learning what a relational database is: if you want databases of objects, use something like mongoDB or couchDB

Comment: safe to assume a large project with several concurrent users could use such a construct though?

Comment: It all depends on the data needs of your project: where your data is structured and has relationships between different elements of data, then you use a relational database; when data is unstructured then a NoSQL database is appropriate... pretty much all databases should support multiple concurrent users

Answer (score 0):

(16) denotes the size in  `VARCHAR(16)`

for index also the same.the argument depicts the length of the index.

```
index_col_name:
    col_name [(length)] [ASC | DESC]
```

for example in case of `INDEX(auth(6))`,the length of the index is 6.

Comment: as in character length? is this always the case?

Comment: thats depends on you and your code requirement,how much size you want to allocate for that datatype.

Comment: Yes it is always the case. As in string length. Int(11) means it can store 11 digits long numbers

Comment: @JoniSalmi ya absolutely true but again it depends on your requirement.